# Modify query posts

Tags: wp-query

I don't want to use pre_get_posts.

```
           $args = array(
                //'posts_per_page'   => $posts,
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'paged'            => $page,           
            );
```

Now I want to modify `posts_per_page` to do that I have done

```
$args['posts_per_page'] = 3,
```

Finally `$query  = new WP_Query($args);`
But no luck. Should I use pre_get_post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have php syntax error. Anyway you can both use

```
$args['posts_per_page'] = 3;
```

or

```
$args['posts_per_page'] = array('3');
```